# common "socket.io event listener" to listen throughout the whole ionic mobile application

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, socket.io, real-time

i am developing real time communication application(like chat application) using ionic framework.For this i am using socket.io (nodejs) as back-end.

whenever client application receives a event from (nodejs)server,the corresponding action*(i.e notification,ex: 'you have received new message')* to be taken irrespective of in which page user is currently present.

on searching lot, i found that to work with socket io events we need to make use of angularjs factory(service). **Which means if i make use of a factory i need to inject the factory(socket factory) to each and every controller present in my application in-order to make it work throughout the application, which is a big cumbersome .**

1. Is there any optimized way to achieve this in angularjs(ionic).Like
       some global event listener or a global service which starts when
       application started and keep on listening until application closes.
2. Is there any option where if i put event handler code which will
           work over all views of angularjs application(independent of specific
           controllers).

Comment: Why are you using ionic?

Comment: since i am developing a cordova hybrid mobile application...